# Installing Ubuntu for the first time, purple screen of death

Tags: installation, boot

Today I went out and bought myself a 1.5 TB external hard drive with the intentions of using it for Ubuntu, possibly running a server with Ubuntu Server and using this hard drive as opposed to the hard drive in the computer already that has some damage(It still works it's just not in the best condition plus it's capacity is only 80 GB.)

The problem I'm having is when I select either Windows 7 or Ubuntu(Ubuntu obviously) it takes me to a purple screen with two options: "Ubuntu, with Linux" and "Ubuntu, with Linux recovery console".

When I select the first one I just get a purple screen, when I select the second one I get a black screen with a ton of white command lines attempting to install(so I'm assuming) drivers and whatever else recovery console is supposed to do(I haven't really messed around with Ubuntu or Linux in general much at all.)

I'd really like to be able to troubleshoot this successfully, thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are messing up with something else. The OS selector is the GRUB. Probably that GRUB is damaged. You could insert a live USB CD, boot into "Try mode" and run the terminal.

`sudo update-grub`

It could fix your problem. Probably.